# Mocking native (jni calls ) in java test class

Tags: android, unit-testing, java-native-interface

I am not able to find a way to mock native calls wither using Mockito or Powermock. Can someone help.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have:

```
public class Foo {
    public native String helloFromJni();
}
```

If you're able to use PowerMockito you could mock the native call like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
public class FooUnitTest {
    Foo foo;

    @Before
    public void perTestSetup {
        foo = PowerMockito.spy(Foo());
        PowerMockito.doReturn("Hello").when(foo, "helloFromJni");
    }
}
```